# How to properly model an XML node with Attributes?

Tags: c#, model, xml-serialization

I'm trying to consume an XML feed and convert it into a model.

Some of the XML looks like this.

```xml
<guid isPermaLink="false">
    http://example.com/foo/bar
</guid>
```

In trying to model this, I'm using

```csharp
[XmlElement("guid")]
public string Guid { get; set; }

[XmlElement("guid")]
public m_Guid Guid { get; set; }
public class m_Guid
{
    [XmlAttribute("isPermaLink")]
    public bool isPermaLink { get; set; }
}
```

but obviously VS is throwing an error

> This member is defined more than once.

I'm simply trying to figure out how to model this so that at the end of it all, I can use

```csharp
var theGuid = someItem.Guid;
var guidIsPermaLink = someItem.Guid.isPermaLink;
```

Just hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. I'm kind of new to modeling like this.

---

Here's another example of confusing markup that needs to be modeled in a similar way.

```xml
<link>http://example.com/foo/bar/</link>
<atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://example.com/foo/bar/&format=rss"/>
```

needs to be modeled so that we can do this

```csharp
var link = someItem.Link;
var linkType = someItem.Link.type;
var linkHref = someItem.Link.href;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could model it like this:

```
public class Guid 
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool IsPermaLink { get; set; }

    // and the element value
    [XmlTextAttribute]
    public string Value;
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}
...
var theGuid = someItem.Guid.Value;
var guidIsPermaLink = someItem.Guid.IsPermaLink;
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. I was hoping to not have to use `.value`, but I'll settle for this for now.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell If you don't want to have to call `.Value` then you could always override `.ToString()` and have that return `Value` which means you could just call `someItem.Guid`.